# A time tracking Android app with timers integrable with Tasker to log Windows tasks?

Tags: windows, android, automation, time-management, timer

I want to track how much I work, make music, meditate and read.

I imagine I can use the Eventghost plugin with Autoremote and Tasker to tell an Android time tracking app how much time I've spent on the above tasks.

**Is there any Android app that can do this?**

- **Work** - logged by simply measuring how much time I'm logged in to different users on my computer; a fair approximation of actual work done.
- **Music** - log how long I have Ableton open per day.
- **Meditate/Read** - Open the Android app, see your list of tasks, and have each timed task have a on/off record button so you can time your sessions without having to use an external app (not a must but would be a very elegant solution).

Visual TimeAnalyzer for Windows can log Work and Music making for $39, but it's not ideal and there's no way to get the data over to android through the app.

Xpert-Timer Time Tracking for Android has on/off recording for timed tasks, but not sure it can integrate with Tasker.